# iOS 9.0.1 update fails to update

Tags: software-update, software

My iPhone 6 won't let me download iOS 9.0.1. I tried downloading it once and it said error occurred, failed to update as it said preparing update.

[image]

So I did it again and deleted some storage in case it was that but its still not working!

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: It would be helpful if we could know exactly what the error message was.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't connect to iTunes and perform a non over the air update?

Comment: Is this the error message you are getting?

Comment: iOS is the most unstable thing to upgrade ever. Just use the older version until more time has passed to save yourself trouble from data loss and bricked phones.